# Copying portion of line as integer in Python scripting language

Tags: python, python3

I need to copy timing window into a variable from line of .txt file using Python.

Input file:

```
[Fri Dec 07 18:50:16.775 2018] [    3.610065] dwc3 e2d00000.usb_core: SUCCESS allocating dump_regset memory
[Fri Dec 07 18:50:16.775 2018] [    3.610770] dwc3 e2d00000.usb_core: Soft reset timeout -29631
[Fri Dec 07 18:50:16.775 2018] [    3.614879] dwc3 e2d00000.usb_core: Dump USB registers
```

So from the above input file i need **"3.610770"** value to be copied into integer variable because that line contains **"Soft reset timeout"** string.

I have managed to write some portion of code but unable to proceed further.

Python script snippet:

```
import sys
inFile = sys.argv[1]

with open(inFile) as fp:
    line = fp.readline()

    while line:
        if "Soft reset timeout" in line:
        #print line
            if "[    " in line:
            #To Do...

        #if "Dump USB registers" in line:
        line = fp.readline()
```

Comment: Reading `3.610770` as an integer would result in reading `3`. Is that really what you are looking for? [Have you tried looking for an answer to your question yet?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36343646/1129682)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `string.split()` you can achieve this. You need to use `[` and `]` to split a string into two parts. Then get the part of the string you want. To remove whitespaces you can use `string.strip()`

```
import sys
input_file=sys.argv[1]
with open(input_file) as fp:
    lines=fp.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        if "Soft reset timeout" in line:
            #print(line)
            second_field=line.split("[")[2]
            timeout_str=second_field.split("]")[0]
            timeout_value=timeout_str.strip()
            print(timeout_value)
```

If you want integer value from the float number '3.610770' you can use `int(timeout_value)`

Answer (score 0):

Get the part of the sub-string you want to convert into a variable (myVar). You can then cast the variable to an integer: `int(myVar)`

See [Is there a way to substring a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/663171/is-there-a-way-to-substring-a-string) and [How to convert strings into integers in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642154/how-to-convert-strings-into-integers-in-python)